# Applescript: copy the selected text and assign it to a var. Then replace the spaces inbetween with -

Tags: applescript

Here's a screenshot of my Mouse Gesture App.
I right-click and draw a gesture with my mouse, the app can execute an AppleScript that I put in the right-bottom box.

The scenario for the script is that:

- I select a word or two on Chrome
- I right-click and draw the gesture with my mouse to trigger the script. Then the script gets the selected word and edits it.

---

- How can the script get the word?
- My thought is:
- "System COPY command"  then  "PASTE from Clipboard to a Variable in script"

If you have other better way, that would be great.

---

1. After getting the word, edit it by replacing spaces in between with "-" dashes.

   ```
                  i.e.   "hook up"  -->  "hook-up"
   ```
2. Then open a new tab in Chrome where URL is :
   **https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-simplified/hook-up**  **Here "hook-up" should be the selected keyword**

[image]

script generated by ChatGPT, but it doesn't work.

```
set theText to (the clipboard as text)

set theText to replace_spaces(theText)

set theURL to "www.dictionary.com/" & theText

tell application "Google Chrome"

   activate

   set currentTab to the active tab of the first window

   set URL of currentTab to theURL

end tell

on replace_spaces(theText)

   set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "

   set theText to theText as text

   set theText to theText's text items as string

   set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "-"

   set theText to theText as text

   set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""

   return theText

end replace_spaces
```

Comment: [text item delimiters](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW22) are your friend.  There doesn’t appear to be a spellcheck - did you mean https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/ ?

Comment: @red_menace  Sir, I've made my question clearer I guess. Could you help please.

Comment: For how the script can get the word, use a service - that will get the selected word directly.

Comment: what is the Mac service, could you show me the code, please.

Comment: For an app, you can take a look at the [Services Implementation Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000101-SW1), if using Automator, it is called a **Quick Action**.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with ChatGPT's script (no surprises there!) The replace_spaces method was totally wrong. Other potential issues were not ensuring that Google Chrome was running and that it had at least one open window. Also, the format of the URL was not quite right to work with that site.

**This works in my testing.**

```
use AppleScript version "2.4"
use scripting additions

set theText to (the clipboard as text)

set theText to "hook up" -- for testing only, then comment this out

set theText to replace_spaces(theText)

set theURL to "https://www.dictionary.com/browse/" & theText

if application "Google Chrome" is not running then
    launch application "Google Chrome"
    delay 1
end if

tell application "Google Chrome"
    
    activate
    
    if (count of windows) is 0 then
        make new window
    end if
    
    set currentTab to the active tab of the first window
    
    set URL of currentTab to theURL
    
end tell

on replace_spaces(theText)
    
    set savedTIDs to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "
    set theTextItems to theText's text items
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "-"
    set theText to theTextItems as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to savedTIDs
    return theText
    
end replace_spaces
```

Comment: BTW, it's not clear to me what is the relevance of the screen shot in your question.

Comment: for those who is not familiar with Mouse Gesture tools, Here's few apps you can try. It massively increase our daily productivity on computer.  
[XGesture](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/16710/xgestures)   
[WGesture](https://www.yingdev.com/projects/wgestures2)

Comment: Thank you very much, Ron.  I've updated my question. The only missing part of the script now is "getting the selected word into the script".

Comment: In chrome, select AND copy the text, which puts it on the clipboard. Then "set theText to (the clipboard as text)” in the script gets it (comment out the line after that — it was just for testing)

Comment: the COPY should be done by the script, I only select and trigger the script.
So what should I put as COPY here before "set theText to (the clipboard as text)"?   Thank you very much, Ron.

Comment: You tell me. What text do you want to copy? Where do you expect the search term text to come from?

Comment: Basically I only manually select a word on a webpage or whatever, and press right-click and draw a figure. Then the script is triggered to execute and do the other jobs. Here is a short screen record demonstrating. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fqHix6rmOM-DH7WQeWmS5v5yXngL1Qz1/view?usp=drivesdk)     So before "set theText to (the clipboard as text),  there should a "Command + C".

Comment: Click to select the word,, press Command-C, and then right-click the selection again and draw your gesture.